# Getting error TS2304: Cannot find name 'T' when using drag-drop dropped EventEmitter in Angular 7

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-cdk

I am getting the error TS2304: Cannot find name 'T' when I try to use the dropped EventEmitter available in angular/cdk/drag-drop.

I'd appreciate any help.

Here is my ts file:

```js
import { Component, OnInit, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
import { DragDropModule, CdkDragDrop } from '@angular/cdk/drag-drop';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-scrum-values',
  templateUrl: './scrum-values.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./scrum-values.component.css']
})
export class ScrumValuesComponent implements OnInit {

  @Output('cdkDropDropped') 
    dropped: EventEmitter<CdkDragDrop<T, any>> = 
      new EventEmitter<CdkDragDrop<T, any>>();

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

Here is my tsconfig file:

```js
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "importHelpers": true,
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    // "skipLibCheck": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "types" : [
      "core-js"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es2017",
      "dom"
    ],
    "module": "es2015",
    "baseUrl": "./"
  }
}
```

Comment: `T` here is a generic type that does not exist at runtime but only compile time. And it is not defined anywhere in your class. What is the **type** you want to emit on drop?

Comment: Makes perfect sense. Thanks Harun.

Comment: Glad to help :)